# HTML Map Image not working

Tags: html, dictionary, area, imagemap

I'm a beginner so please take it easy on me. I will be trying to create several area's but I'm trying to get this one area to work first. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I have for code:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="1000" height="900" usemap="#CWS" />

<map name="CWS">
<area shape="rect" coords="484, 801, 640, 900" href="CWS/Function_Menu.jpg" alt="Function_Menu">
</map>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: read this http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/map-and-area-elements.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually working fine.

Your image has size of 1000x900px.
In rectangle area the coords you type in are:
`coords="left, top, width, height"`. (Left, top means the distance (in px) from left top corner of your image.) Check your values.
[Or just take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q5r3.jpg)

Comment: Lol! YES! I'm an idiot! haha. I'm going to try and figure this out. I opened the image in paint and used the coords that shows at the bottom. Clearly not the same thing. I'll shirt the image to 1000X900px then do that. Thanks!